# Get user count and actual userdata in a csv file in Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I am trying to get the user count and the actual userinformation through get-aduser but fail miserably.

```
    Get-ADUser -Server $test -Credential $1cred -Filter{enabled -eq $true} | Where-Object { $_.DistinguishedName -notlike '*OU=.Service Accounts,*' -and $_.samaccountname -notlike '*health*' } | Select-object Samaccountname,surname,givenname | Where { $excludedusers -NotContains$_.Samaccountname } | format-list > 'C:\Scripts\Test\enabled_users_and count.csv'
```

Is the current code. I can add a .count before format-list like this:

```
(Get-ADUser -Server $test -Credential $1cred -Filter{enabled -eq $true} | Where-Object { $_.DistinguishedName -notlike '*OU=.Service Accounts,*' -and $_.samaccountname -notlike '*health*' } | Select-object Samaccountname,surname,givenname | Where { $excludedusers -NotContains$_.Samaccountname }).count
```

But I only get the count of the users, as earlier said, I need both.

Extremely thankful for the help.

Comment: Welcome as a new user to SO. Please take the [tour] and also read [ASK]. You shouldn't select all powershell tags, but the one matching your environment, see tag description by hovering the mouse over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need Two different things, Count don't need to be a field in the csv, you can get it by the line count of the final output

You might need the count for the console use, anyway it's not logically right to save it in the final output. (if I understand you right)

You can save it to a variable, then do export or count check...

```
$Users = Get-ADUser -Server $test -Credential $1cred -Filter{enabled -eq $true} | 
Where-Object { $_.DistinguishedName -notlike '*OU=.Service Accounts,*' -and $_.samaccountname -notlike '*health*' } |
Where { $excludedusers -NotContains $_.Samaccountname }
```

Export:

```
$Users | Select-object Samaccountname,surname,givenname | 
Export-CSV 'C:\Scripts\Test\enabled_users_and count.csv'
```

Check Count:

```
$Users.Count
```